# slideUp/slideDown is not consistent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to `slideDown()` a `div` when the appropriate `radio` is selected, and `slideUp` the active one.

However, as it is now, in some cases it's being pushed down, in other cases pushed up.

(Private -> Shop = Up, Shop -> Private = Down)

I want it to always be pushed down. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the current state on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mfmU7/

And the raw Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#private").click(function() {

        $('#registration-brand, #registration-shop').slideUp();
        $('#registration-private').slideDown();         

    });

    $("#shop").click(function() {

        $('#registration-brand, #registration-private').slideUp();
        $('#registration-shop').slideDown();

    });

    $("#brand").click(function() {

        $('#registration-shop, #registration-private').slideUp();
        $('#registration-brand').slideDown();

    });

});
```

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome

Comment: I am using Chrome as well. Try switching between private/shop, you will see one way is up, the other way is down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all about position in the DOM (or z-index):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btn').on('click', function() {
        var that = $('#registration-'+this.id);
        $('.registration-type:visible').not(that).slideUp().before(that.slideDown());
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mfmU7/2/)

Comment: This works by moving the div that is becoming visible so it precedes ( in the DOM) the other two divs that are becoming hidden. All three of the animations occur "at the same time" (accounting for the one div that's hidden at the start and stays hidden). Since the one appearing is always "above" the others (or more towards the top), the motion seems the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem (that some slide up visually and some slide down visually) is caused because, in your original code, all the animations are occurring at once and the divs are vertically placed one above the other. So the top one looks like it is sliding down but the other two, while sliding down, look like they are popping up from the bottom because of the one that is in the process of hiding.

I like doing it this way so one action doesn't start until the others are over:

```
$("#private").click(function() {

    $('#registration-brand, #registration-shop').slideUp(function() {
        $('#registration-private').slideDown();
    });

});
```

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mfmU7/1/)

The problem with doing that (like I usually do) is that the function gets called twice, once when the already hidden div finishes hiding, which is almost immediately, and once after the other div finishes hiding (4/10 sec later). The second one does nothing because the appearing div is already fully visible (or almost so).

So ... another solution is needed.

This one has a whole different look because it waits until both slide up actions are done (even though one div is already hidden) before starting the slide down. The 'promise()' creates something that will be finished when all the 'slideUp()' calls complete their animation and the 'always()' calls the function when that is done.

```
$("#private").click(function() {

    $('#registration-brand, #registration-shop').slideUp().promise().always(function() {
        $('#registration-private').slideDown();
    });

});
```

[ALTERNATE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mfmU7/5/)

Comment: This solves the problem because it always finishes hiding before it starts making one appear.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and I resolve it by adding:

```
position:absolute; 
bottom:85%;
```

to CSS and it solves your isue here

but then u have to again place those divs

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/isair/mfmU7/4/

Comment: This works by positioning all three divs in the same absolute spot on the screen. As they become visible and hidden, the visible one appears  to slide down, truly.